# Linq Orderby random ThreadSafe for use in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, s#arp-architecture

i'm using Asp.net MVC with Sharp Architecture.

I have this code:

```
return _repositoryKeyWord.FindAll(x => x.Category.Id == idCAtegory)
                .Take(50).ToList();
```

How can i order by  random?
Note: i don't want to order the 50 extracted items, i want order before and then extract 50 items.

thks

Comment: Are you saying that you want the entire list randomized and then you want to retrieve the first 50 items?

Comment: This question does not duplicate the linked question. This question specifically denotes ASP.NET which requires ThreadSafe random access. The linked question makes no mention of ThreadSafe

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way to achieve efficiently is to add a column to your data `Shuffle` that is populated with a random int (as each record is created).

The query to access the table then becomes ...

```
Random random = new Random();
int seed = random.Next();
result = result.OrderBy(s => (~(s.Shuffle & seed)) & (s.Shuffle | seed)); // ^ seed);
```

This does an XOR operation in the database and orders by the results of that XOR.

Advantages:-

1. Efficient: SQL handles the
   ordering, no need to fetch the whole
   table
2. Repeatable: (good for
   testing) - can use the same random
   seed to generate the same random
   order
3. Works on most (all?) Entity Framework supported 
   databases

This is the approach used by my home automation system to randomize playlists.  It picks a new seed each day giving a consistent order during the day (allowing easy pause / resume capabilities) but a fresh look at each playlist each new day.

Comment: This solution made me go ooooo and ahhhh.

Comment: jfar: Me too; 'tis pwesome.  Although I just used the PK (which is an int) instead of a Shuffle field and it works just fine.  Thanks Hightechrider!

Comment: This is just amazing! I used PK aswell. Performance is outstanding

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in T-Sql as described [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm). I don't think you can do it in linq without loading the whole result set into memory and then throwing most of it away, which you do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
return _repositoryKeyWord.FindAll(x => x.Category.Id == idCAtegory)
                .OrderBy(x => r.Next())
                .Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: Hah, I like that.

If it's using quick sort though, that might crash. I know that trying to use Array.Sort on an inconsistent parameter will cause an exception.

Comment: I'd like to see the sql that generates. Is it returning the entire table, then sorting and throwing away everything but the top 50 records?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that should be .Take(50).OrderBy(x => r.Next()), not the other way around. Edit: never mind, I misread the question.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka: Why, he specifically states he doesn't want to sort just the 50 items? Does the SQL of reversing them generate correctly according to spec?

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to write your own extension method to do it.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return Shuffle(items, random);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Random random)
    {
        // Un-optimized algorithm taken from
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm
        List<T> list = new List<T>(items);
        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--) 
        {
            int j = random.Next(0, i);
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Random.Next isn't thread safe, so you can't use static variable to store shared Random value here.

Comment: And certainly, there must be i--, not i++