# Error: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBitwiseAnd' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I'm using s#arp architecture and NHibernate 3.1.

I'd like to randomly select 10 rows from a table and I'm following the advice given in this page [Linq Orderby random ThreadSafe for use in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339192/linq-orderby-random)

The solution involves doing XOR in the database and my query looks like this

```
repo.FindAll()
    .OrderBy(q => ((~(q.QuestionId & seed)) & (q.QuestionId | seed)))
    .Take(10);
```

And I get the following error:
**Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBitwiseAnd' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'**

When I remove '~' from the query I don't get the error. Is this a bug in NHQueryProvider that cannot understand '~' as bitwise operation?

Comment: Does it work with NHibernate 3.3.1?