# Nhibernate queryover order by random

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to write a query which returns randomly ordered results. I've found this post [Linq Orderby random ThreadSafe for use in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339192/linq-orderby-random) which gave me some basic clue how to do that. But i'm getting following exception:

variable 'x' of type 'Accomodations.DAL.Model.Generated.Accomodation' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Here is my query:

```
                var query = session.QueryOver<Accomodation>()
                                   .OrderBy(x => (~(x.Id & seed)) & (x.Id | seed)).Asc; // this is the problematic line of code                    

                if (searchParams.District != 0)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.District.Id == searchParams.District);

                if (searchParams.Region != 0)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Region.Id == searchParams.Region);

                if (searchParams.Location != 0)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Location.Id == searchParams.Location);

                var futureCount = query.Clone().Select(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<int>();

                SearchAccomodationResultItem resultItemAlias = null;

                var futurePage = query                        
                    .SelectList(list => list
                        .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.Id)
                        .Select(x => x.AccomodationType.Id).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.AccomodationTypeId)
                        .Select(x => x.Region.Id).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.RegionId)
                        .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.Title)
                        .Select(x => x.MaxCapacity).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.MaxCapacity)
                        .Select(x => x.MinPrice).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.MinPrice)
                        .Select(x => x.MinStayLength).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.MinStayLength)
                        .Select(x => x.MainImageName).WithAlias(() => resultItemAlias.ImgSrc)                           
                        )                        
                    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SearchAccomodationResultItem>())                        
                    .Skip(skip)                        
                    .Take(searchParams.PageSize)
                    .Future<SearchAccomodationResultItem>();

                searchResults = futurePage.ToList();
                numberOfResults = futureCount.Value;                    
            });
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example of how to do this.  This is a technique that I'm currently using.

http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/nhibernate-queryover-and-newid-or-rand.html

### Edit

Below is taken from the above article and I've modified it slightly to include `Skip` as well.

```
public IList<CmsTestimonial> GetRandomTestimonials(int count, int skip) {  
  return Session  
    .QueryOver<CmsTestimonial>()  
    .OrderByRandom()
    .Take(count)  
    .Skip(skip)
    .List();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if this helps me, because i want to persist the order while the users uses the pagination. Will the pagination work when i use your example?

Comment: Why wouldn't pagination work?  The `OrderByRandom` extension method defined in that posts returns `IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType>`.  Did  you see the example use at the end of the article?  I've posted above if this is unclear.

Comment: Good blog that, wonder who wrote it :) One point about pagination, this wont work as some of the records shown on page one could be shown on page 2 or 3 etc. To have random records for pagination is going to be very tricky as you would need to store ALL results in a table randomy (and maybe for every user)! I would really think why you need random records and paging!

Answer (score 1):

To use the above approach with paging, you could store the seed for the user (on a per session basis probably) and then use the RAND(seed) function in SQL - because you use the same seed, it will generate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers and thus allow paging