# SQLite and List Generic C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to convert some older code for Windows 8 using SQLite.  Below is a code from a previous session that works.

```
using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection("Version=3,uri=file://flashcards0904.db"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqliteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Decks where DeckGroup='" + Global.currentDeckGroup.ToString() + Global.currentDeck.ToString() + "'" + "order by random()";

                List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

                using (SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        myCollection.Add(reader.GetString(0) + "~" + reader.GetString(1) + "~" + reader.GetString(2));
                        Global.words = myCollection.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                Community.CsharpSqlite.FileStream.HandleTracker.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Now, I don't have access to SqliteDataReader and I'm trying to use a List<> function, but I cannot get the "Where" clause to work.  Any help, here is my current code:

```
var root = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolderPath;
var dbPath= Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolderPath,"flashcards0904.db");

using( var db= new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
// Here is location for the missing Where Clause"

    var list= db.Table<Decks>.Where??????? .ToList();

 }
```

Hope this explains the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list= db.Table<Decks>.Where(n=>n.DeckGroup == (Global.currentDeckGroup.ToString() + Global.currentDeck.ToString())).ToList()
```

I'd encourage you to take a look at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

There are a large number of examples there that should help you get a handle on LINQ to SQL.

Paolo Moretti noticed that you were using `order by random()` in your previous implementation. If you would like to do this in LINQ you can do the following as found here: [Linq Orderby random ThreadSafe for use in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339192/linq-orderby-random)

```
Random random = new Random();
int seed = random.Next();
var list= db.Table<Decks>.Where(n=>n.DeckGroup == (Global.currentDeckGroup.ToString() + Global.currentDeck.ToString())).OrderBy(s => (~(s.Shuffle & seed)) & (s.Shuffle | seed)).ToList(); // ^ seed);
```

Comment: The original query was also shuffling the decks using `"order by random()"`

Comment: You're right, I wasn't sure if he wanted help with that part. There is a clear example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339192/linq-orderby-random

Comment: Excellent response, Mucho Thanks