# Select 2 random null values in a Column and replace them with a value

Tags: c#, postgresql

my table looks kinda like this

```
ID  Name Username
--  ---- ----
1   A    null
2   B    charmander
3   C    null
4   D    null
```

I want to select 2 random null values from column Username and replace both with pikachu.

Is there a way I can to this in C#?

Appreciate any help

Comment: *Is there a way* - the answer is typically "yes". Could you make the question slightly more involved? Show us what you've done, how you access your database, what you're stuck with..

Comment: If your question amounts to "how to pick a random row from a SQL table?", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339298/224370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tab
SET username = 'pikachu'
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM tab
             WHERE username IS NULL
             ORDER BY random()
             LIMIT 2);
```

Yes, there are ways to run an SQL statement from C#, for example using the Npgsql provider.

Comment: You can run a query via Npgsql, right?

Comment: yeah ich used NpgsqlCommand command = db.CreateConnection().CreateCommand(). it worked with other spq statements. your sql statement looks very good but it says "Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601"  Syntax Error :/ 
& the column username is  a foreign key

Comment: What exactly is the text message that goes with the 42601?

Comment: Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: Syntax error at »=«

Comment: I had a typo in `LIMIT`, but that syntax error is not possible. Are you sure your query is exactly what I wrote?

Comment: this is what i wrote :/ idk whats the prob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242082/discussion-between-reddragon2001-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: You have to put spaces between the words. `"UPDATE cards" + "SET player"` is wrong; it should be `"UPDATE cards " + "SET player"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your table name is MyData.
We create an instance of Random method to generate a random number of the list then we gonna replace the matching number of the index to pikachu

So try this out:

```
var random = new Random();

var usernameList = _context.MyData.select (x=>x.Username).ToList();

int index = random.Next(usernameList.Count);

var newList = usernameList .Select(s => s.Replace(usernameList[index],"pikachu")).ToList();


})
```

I've not tested this on my device but i think the concept will work for you!

**NOTE**: you may need to take care of converting int->string if needed. Also, try repeat the process for getting the second random element.